# Amcharts time series data not displaying

Tags: json, graph, amcharts

I'm trying to pull some time and temperature data into Amcharts.  The data is regularly collected temperature data (every 10 minutes).  The data displays but appears to be stacked on top of each other. See example image:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9YQ5.jpg)

The data format (from a php script) is:

```
[{"timestamp":"2015-10-26 04:44:33","temp":24.9,"ID":"AA"},{"timestamp":"2015-10-26 04:54:31","temp":25.1,"ID":"AA"},{"timestamp":"2015-10-26 05:04:30","temp":25.2,"ID":"AA"}.....
```

The script code I am using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Indoor temperature</title>
    <script src="amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="amcharts/amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="amcharts/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script>
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "dataLoader": {
            "url": "/sensor-data.php?action=csv_data&id='AB'&period=24"
            },
        "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/",
        "categoryField": "timestamp",
        "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS",
        "startDuration": 1,
        "categoryAxis": {
            "parseDates": true,
            "autoGridCount": true,
            "minPeriod" : "ss"
        },
        "graphs": [ {
            "valueField": "temp",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
            "lineThickness ": 2,
            "lineAlpha": 0.5
        } ]
    } );
    </script>
</head>
    <body>       
        <div id="chartdiv" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong to prevent the data from being displayed correctly?

Comment: my guess will be that your data is not sorted correctly by date.
if you want more help supply the entire data array and not just a small sample. and also edit your code to have CDN links instead of locals `amcharts/amcharts.js` this won't load.
and if you really want help.. open up a working fiddle that shows your error. you'll get very quick answers

Comment: thanks @LiranBo, see my answer below. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had the dates not coming out of the PHP script as a date format **AND** I had the date being formatted wrong from a python script to the php to the javascript.

Thanks for looking at this.